# How to execute an M- file line by line in Octave?

Tags: matlab, debugging, octave, ddd-debugger

I don't have Matlab installed in my computer, but found I can use Octave in my Ubuntu machine that I installed long time ago. The Octave version on my CentOs machine is too low to run the program.

In VOC2012 devtools, I see `example_classifier.m` program which I can run by entering `octave` in the shell and  typing `example_classifier` in the Octave shell. I can see the result files and graphs coming up.

But I need to analyze several M-file programs. Being able to analyze it line by line using debugger is crucial for an efficient work.

How can I use Octave to debug/analyze the code graphically? (I mean I want to use `next`, `step-in`, `finish` kind of commands inside the programs like I do in ddd with gdb).

Comment: You should always mention the version of the software (GNU Octave in this case) you are using. And what is the point with your CentOs machine?

Comment: The octave version on my centos 6.9 machine is 3.4.3, and I saw octaive gui version is availble from 3.8. On my ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS machine, it's 3.8.1.

Comment: Also, I see this kinds of errors on centos version, which I don't see in ubuntu machine, other than the gui thing.. 
error: invalid conversion from real matrix to real scalar
error: octave_base_value::int_value (): wrong type argument `matrix'
error: addpath: expecting final argument to be 1 or 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the Octave debugger from the command line in the same way as you can access the MATLAB debugger:

- [`dbstop`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/dbstop.html) defines a breakpoint. This can be used any time, Octave will enter debug mode when the breakpoint is hit.

  For example, `dbstop myfunction` will create a breakpoint at the beginning of the function `myfunction`, executing the function will immediately start the debugging at the top of that file.
- [`dbstep`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/dbstep.html) executes the next line. You can also do `dbstep in`.
- While in the debugger, you can examine variables in the function’s workspace just like you would in the base workspace under normal operation: type the name of a variable to see its value, use `plot` or any other command, etc.

See [the documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.3/Debugging.html) for a full list of debug commands.

Comment: Hi, I asked how to start the debugger, dbstop and dbstep is for when I am already in the debug mode executing the .m program. Could you please add just a little more explanation on how to enter that debug mode? for people not familiar with(or forgot) octave and matlab..

Comment: @ChanKim: `dbstop` can be used at any time, also (and especially) outside of debug mode. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I found I can just type
octave --force-gui
and open the program (example_classifier.m)
and in the editor pane (one of right side panes, you ca select at bottom right),
press the 'run' button (green triangular shape).
you can set break-points, single-step, and so on. (you can see the buttons.)

[image]